# Dimension of a representation needs to be the same as the number of its invariant subspaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory

Does a representation of a group have the same number of invariant subspaces as the  dimension of the representation?

Supposing a **matrix representation of a group (W)** whose elements in the representation are matrices of dimension $n \times n$ with $n ∈\mathbb N$. Are there always going to be **n linear independent vectors** that are going to be **invariant subspaces**?

Or is it possible that the dimensions of the **matrix** and **the number of invariant subspaces** are **different** (i.e. $\dim(W)=n$ and $\dim(V)=m$ with $n≠m$ being  $V$ the span of the invariant subspaces)?

Comment: If you consider a 2-dimensional complex representation of the trivial group, there are infinitely many invariant subspaces, so I think your question is a little strangely stated. On the other hand, if you take a two-dimensional irreducible representation (for example, there is one of these for the symmetric group $S_3$), then the only invariant subspaces are $0$ and the whole representation.

Comment: You seem confused about what an invariant subspace is.  A vector cannot be an invariant subspace (it is not a subspace at all!), and the span of all invariant subspaces is always $V$ since $V$ itself is an invariant subspace (but this says nothing at all about the _number_ of invariant subspaces).